# How can I remove a word from a string?

Tags: php, string, php-7

I am carrying out a little experiment, appending the string JERRY to every sql keyword in the sql statement by checking from an array of SQL keywords which I specify. I want to remove the string JERRY from the search variable, so that if I typed a' UNION (SELECT 1, fname, username, password FROM users);-- in the search input field, the printed sql statement should look like this;

SELECTJERRY * FROMJERRY shopping WHEREJERRY title LIKEJERRY '%a' UNION (SELECT 1, fname, username, password FROM users);-- %'

The goal is that I don't want the SQL Keywords in the input search variable to have the string JERRY.

BUT right now, this is what I get;

SELECTJERRY * FROMJERRY shopping WHEREJERRY title LIKEJERRY '%a' UNIONJERRY (SELECT 1, fname, username, password FROMJERRY users);-- %'

How can i achieve this?

```
$search = $_GET['search'];
if (empty($search)) {
    echo "Please fill in the search bar";

    exit();
}

$keywords = ["SELECT", "FROM", "WHERE", "LIKE", "AND", "OR", "ON","UNION", "JOIN"];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM shopping WHERE title LIKE '%$search%'";
$splittedSql = explode(" ", $sql);

foreach ($splittedSql as $sl) {

    if (in_array($sl, $keywords)) {

        $newstatement = $sl . "JERRY" . ' ';
    } else {
        $newstatement = $sl . ' ';
    }
    echo $newstatement;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do here.  Your list of MySQL keywords is far from complete.  If this has something to do with injection attacks, you should just use a prepared statement and then forget about it.

Comment: Like I mentioned, I am experimenting a simple concept. Yes this is about Injection attack but I know of prepared statements and other various ways of solving the problem. I just need to try something out.

Comment: SELECTJERRY * FROMJERRY shopping WHEREJERRY title LIKEJERRY '%a' UNION (SELECT 1, fname, username, password FROM users);-- %' If i can get the result to be this, I can validate that only keywords with the string JERRY are the real sql keywords to be processed and if otherwise, discard it as just text. Just trying to develop a new concept for Injection Attack

Comment: actually there are so many ways to do this. like temporarily change the `$search` strings so it won't affect by the `explode`, if you're up to it

Comment: @Shizukura if you could show some code examples, I'll appreciate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you're checking your static query with a user supplied `$search` value included in it. Achieving your desired results would require a limit on the keyword replacements.

One approach would be to first check the user supplied `$search` value for the specified keywords, If it exists, alter your static query. Then you can apply the user supplied `$search` value after-the-fact, which can be accomplished easily using `sprintf`.

Instead of exploding the query, you can use `preg_replace` to apply the keyword values all at once, using a capture group `()` and replacement value of `$1JERRY`.
 You can use word boundaries `\b` on the pattern to avoid false positives on words like `sAND`, `tON`,`lORe`, etc.

Lastly using `stripos` to check the `$search` value as opposed to `in_array()` and the `/i` regex modifier, will allow the `$keyword` matching and replacements to be case-insensitive.

### Approach 1: https://3v4l.org/ie2Mj

```
$search = 'a\' UNION (SELECT 1, fname, username, password FROM users);--';

$keywords = ["SELECT", "FROM", "WHERE", "LIKE", "AND", "OR", "ON","UNION", "JOIN"];

//sprintf requires textual percent signs to be escaped as %%
$query = 'SELECT * FROM shopping WHERE title LIKE \'%%%s%%\'';
foreach ($keywords as $w) {
    if (false !== stripos($search, $w)) {
        //found a keyword build the replacement capture groups.
        $patterns = '/\b(' . implode('|', $keywords) . ')\b/i';
        $query = preg_replace($patterns, '$1JERRY', $query);
        break;
    }
}
printf($query, $search);
```

---

An alternative to iterating over the `$keywords` would be to use `preg_match` to determine if the `$search` value contains a keyword value.

### Approach 2: https://3v4l.org/iVbBc

```
$search = 'a\' UNION (SELECT 1, fname, username, password FROM users);--';
$keywords = ["SELECT", "FROM", "WHERE", "LIKE", "AND", "OR", "ON","UNION", "JOIN"];
$patterns = '/\b(' . implode('|', $keywords) . ')\b/i';
$query = 'SELECT * FROM shopping WHERE title LIKE \'%%%s%%\'';

if (preg_match($patterns, $search)) {
    $query = preg_replace($patterns, '$1JERRY', $query);
}
printf($query, $search);
```

---

Results for both approaches:

```
SELECTJERRY * FROMJERRY shopping WHEREJERRY title LIKEJERRY '%a' UNION (SELECT 1, fname, username, password FROM users);--%'
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `$search` will be affected by `explode` , using whitespace, we can prevent this by replacing whitespaces with unique characters:

```
  $search = str_replace(" ","uniquecharacters",$search);
```

and then replace those unique characters back with white space/s

```
$keywords = ["SELECT", "FROM", "WHERE", "LIKE", "AND", "OR", "ON","UNION", "JOIN"];
$search = str_replace(" ","uniquecharacters",$search);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM shopping WHERE title LIKE '%$search%'";
$splittedSql = explode(" ", $sql);

foreach ($splittedSql as $sl) {

    if (in_array($sl, $keywords)) {  
       $newstatement = $sl . "JERRY" . ' ';
    } else {
       $newstatement = str_replace("uniquecharacters"," ",$sl);
       $newstatement = $sl . ' ';
    }
    echo $newstatement;
 }
```